# Pronom réfléchi avec «on» indéterminé

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-réfléchis

Lorsque le pronom « on » désigne un sujet indéterminé, comment indiquer qu’un certain événement est applicable à ce même sujet indéterminé ?

Par exemple :

- On veut éviter que la porte ne `pronom réfléchi` ferme au nez.
- On ne tient pas à ce qu’il `pronom réfléchi` arrive quelque accident malencontreux.

Si le narrateur se détache entièrement du ***on*** invoqué, ***nous*** demeure-t-il possible ? Souhaitable ?

On commente ci-dessous qu’une reformulation pourrait faire mieux l’affaire, ce qui me semble recevable dans la mesure où on ne se bute pas à une tournure où elle devient plus difficile à manier, comme celle ayant généré cette question de ma part :

- Tel un vendeur itinérant et entreprenant, on met le pied dans la porte afin d’éviter qu’on ne `pronom réfléchi` ferme la porte au nez.

Comment: Pour moi oui, « nous » convient, même si cela introduit une ambiguïté pareille à celle qu'entraîne « se » (est-ce que « on » signifie quelqu'un d'autre qui s'occupe de nous !). Mais comme c'est ma deuxième langue je ne suis pas certain.

Answer (score 5):

Selon *Le Bon usage*, 14<sup>e</sup> édition, §754e, déclare :

> S’il faut exprimer un pronom personnel (*se* et *soi* étant exclus) ou un possessif renvoyant à *on* pris dans le sens indéfini, on se sert, soit de ***nous***, ***notre*** (le locuteur se met dans la collectivité : d’autres + moi), soit de ***vous***, ***votre*** (le locuteur s’efface et ne se met pas dans la collectivité) .

J’imagine qu’on pourra ajouter les pluriel de ces possessifs aux propositions : ***nos*** et ***vos***.

À cet article, on spécifie aussi en note que :

> - Le même choix existe lorsqu’on doit renvoyer à un ***on*** implicite, à une collectivité indéterminée ;
> - L’emploi de la 3<sup>e</sup> personne rend [par exemple] cette phrase peu nette :
>     *Déclarer par un acte ce que l’on veut qui soit exécuté après **sa** mort* (Dictionnaire de l’Académie, 1935, s.v. tester)

Et les exemples littéraires, classiques chez Grevisse :

> - *Quand on se plaint de tout, il ne **vous** arrive rien de bon.* —J. Chardonne
> - *On ne refuse pas le bonheur quand il frappe à **votre** porte* —Chamson

---

Pour reformuler les phrases proposées, donc, puisque le locuteur s’exlut de la collectivité, tel que spécifié dans la question, et puisque la 3<sup>e</sup> personne n’est assurément pas la solution dans ces cas particuliers<sup>1</sup> :

- *On veut éviter que la porte ne **vous** ferme au nez.*
- *On ne tient pas à ce qu’il **vous** arrive quelque accident malencontreux.*
- *Tel un vendeur itinérant et entreprenant, on met le pied dans la porte afin d’éviter qu’on ne **vous** ferme la porte au nez.*

---

À l’oral, la distinction est peut-être un peu subtile pour le locuteur moyen (au nombre desquels je me compte), et la première comme la deuxième personne du pluriel passerait sans doute sans problème.

---

<sup>1</sup>  D’autres exemples auraient pu utiliser la troisième personne : *En tant qu’animal, on doit **se** nourrir pour survivre, mais la tarte au sirop d’érable ne sert à rien de plus qu’à réjouir **sa** dent sucrée. On frémit en grattant **ses** ongles sur un tableau.*

Comment: Merci ! J'ai mieux compris le sujet, et la question, en lisant votre excellente réponse. La différence entre ce que vous abordez vs. ce que vous laissez de côté p/r à ma réponse illustre où se situe mon incompréhension : la différence entre le on implicite, le on pour la collectivité indéterminée, le on pour des personnes indéterminées etc. En plus j'ai identifié une lacune où j'ai de la difficulté à identifier la personne de certains pronoms... il me prend plusieurs secondes par exemple pour exprimer la personne (3e par ex.) représentée par _leur_ ou _se_.

Answer (score 2):

Pour la question du titre prise en général :

Il existe évidemment un pronom réfléchi indéterminé et c'est : **soi**

C'est le **soi** du *soi disant* dans lequel c'est bien *on* qui *se* dit.

À propos de porte, Bernanos : *Qu'importe un asile à qui sut franchir une fois le seuil familier et trouve la porte à refermer derrière soi si légère?*

Pour le cas particulier de la question, l'exemple de Bernanos tombe assez bien et on peut essayer de calquer la syntaxe.

*On veut éviter que la porte ne ferme au nez de soi.*

On peut aussi chercher à calquer Joubert (*Une conscience à soi, une morale à soi, une religion à soi!*) -> *que la porte ne ferme au nez, à soi!* ou... plus mieux tourné grâce à l'inversion

*On veut éviter qu'**à soi**, la porte ne ferme au nez.*

Et de même :

*On ne tient pas à ce qu’à soi(-même), arrive quelque accident malencontreux.*

Bien qu'inusuelles, toutes ces façons de dire sont syntaxiquement et grammaticalement correctes.
De toutes je préfère la dernière mais... juste pour faire mon original évidemment tant *claquer/fermer/balancer la porte au nez* devient une sorte de locution figée c'est à dire implicitement et... *en-soi* :-)... porteuse de l'indéterminé. Le nez en question, c'est déjà le nez de *on*, nul besoin alors d'être explicite.

Je dirai alors plus simplement : *On veut éviter de se prendre la porte dans la gueule...* déportant le problème sur un pronominal à l'infinitif.

Si on accepte de casser la locution figée alors le mieux est sans doute de dire :

*On veut éviter qu'à son nez la porte ne ferme.*

Comment: *Soi* c'est l'équivalent de *moi*, pas de *me* qui serait la forme à utiliser dans les phases proposées. La reformulation est possible, mais c'est pas forcément naturel.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : *"La forme **à utiliser**"* ... lol! Je parle de **syntaxe** ici pas de **devoir**... Si ? HaBOn!

Answer (score 1):

On a la *possibilité conventionnelle* des adages, qui veut qu'un pronom, comme par exemple « son » ait pour antécédent la même personne que celle représentée par le pronom « on » sujet.

- Comme **on** fait **son** lit on se couche.
- **On** n'est jamais mieux servi que par **soi-même**.

Au delà de la syntaxe des adages, il n'y a pas de pronom qui puisse remplir cette fonction convenablement *dans la langue courante* ; il y aura toujours une imprécision dans l'utilisation d'un pronom et cela dans les trois cas possible d'antécédent; la seule possibilité consiste en une utilisation du pronom « nous » suivie d'une spécification de ce pronom.

La phrase de la question originale est transformée parce que les possibilités suivantes [n'appartiennent pas au français](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=porte+leur+ferme+au+nez%2Cporte+nous+ferme+au+nez%2Cporte+te+ferme+au+nez%2Cporte+vous+ferme+au+nez&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) : porte leur ferme au nez, porte nous ferme au nez, porte te ferme au nez, porte vous ferme au nez, etc. On [trouve](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ferme+la+porte+au+nez%2Cfermer+la+porte+au+nez&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cferme%20la%20porte%20au%20nez%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfermer%20la%20porte%20au%20nez%3B%2Cc0) cependant « fermer la porte au nez » et « ferme la porte au nez ». Cela est attesté par le TLFi, qui ne mentionne aucun idiome tel que « la porte ferme au nez ».

- On veut éviter que la porte ne *nous* soit fermée au nez, **à nous qui n'avons pas la pensée d'éviter cela**.
  *Le narrateur ne se considère pas comme faisant partie du groupe que « on » désigne mais comme du groupe du reste.*
- On veut éviter que la porte ne *nous* soit fermée au nez, **à nous tous avec ou non la pensée d'éviter cela**.
  *Le narrateur se considère comme faisant partie de l'ensemble total, pas seulement du groupe restant.*
- On veut éviter que la porte ne *nous* soit fermée au nez, **à nous qui avons ce désir d'éviter cela**.
  *Le narrateur se considère comme faisant partie seulement du groupe que « on » désigne.*