# The "on" subject

Tags: grammaire

I'm a beginner at French, studying verbs conjugation and using "Alter ego +" as a didactic book.

The book presents the verb "avoir" as:

- j'ai
- tu as
- il a
- nous avons
- vous avez
- ils ont

However, some conjugations on the internet also have a subject I have never seen/spotted my teacher using before, "on", just after il/elle and with the same conjugation: "on a".

Who the "on" subject represents? When should it be used? Does it always have the same conjugation as il/elle? And what could be the reasons why the book/my teacher not use it while conjugating?

Comment: duplicate : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8185/17649 https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13910/17649

Comment: more answers :https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6289/17649 https://french.stackexchange.com/q/4601/17649 https://french.stackexchange.com/q/871/17649

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There certainly are near-duplicate questions, but I'll take the opportunity to comment on the context of learning French as a second language since *on* is a common stumbling block.

First, *on* mainly has three possible meanings:

- *Nous*, i.e. **we**, but more standard. In Canada, for example, you might hear politicians use *on* in debates and *nous* in prepared speeches.

  > On est prêt à sortir. Tu viens ?
- The general **they** as in "They say you can hear it a mile away." (Or a general **someone**.)

  > On me dit que tu as obtenu un poste. C'est génial !
- The general **you** as in "You want to switch gears at around 2,500 RPM."

  <sub>Sometimes you'll see *l'on*. Same meaning, slightly more formal. A bit like saying "One ought to ..." in English.</sub>

  > On ne doit jamais mentir à un policier.

All these meanings are conjugated the same as *il*. That's why books that optimize the conjugation system omit it. It's the same reason your book omits *elle*, since that too is redundant with *il*.

From a grammar point of view, that's probably smart for a beginner. But outside of conjugation, it's obviously still essential to learn *elle*, and the same goes for *on*.

Teachers usually turn their attention to *on* later than *nous* (not to mention *elle* !), even though *on* is more common in actual speech. Students learning a language in a traditional grammar-focused way, like I did, might get to a high level before going out into the French-speaking world and wondering... What is this word people use instead of *nous* ?

There are a few reasons why it's taught that way:

- *On* is less grammaticalized in the language, so it has certain difficulties and gaps for expressing some meanings. For example, it's easy to say "ourselves" with *nous* [but not with *on*.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32767/pronom-r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chi-avec-on-ind%C3%A9termin%C3%A9)
- Much classic literature, and even slightly older literature that makes up the exercises and books schools can't afford to replace, uses the more formal *nous*, so there's more reading material.
- Any pronoun that can have three different meanings will make translation confusing.

So for now it's probably a good idea to stick with *nous* when learning French as a second language. However, be aware of *on* in videos or when you practice speaking casually with friends.

In newer language-learning methods that are more focused on natural oral use, such as immersion in Canada, the teacher will use *on* very early in an attempt to mirror how native speakers learn it.

---

<sub>See the comments for further complications regarding this pronoun!</sub>

Comment: The rabbit hole can go deeper (_on_ can equate any and all pronouns) and sometimes in writing it may be required to walk back the garden path. Consider [this](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1708): _on s’est efforcée de décrire la situation de façon objective_ ... this is a feminine _je_... Teaching such intricacies must be challenging indeed. Thanks!

Comment: To the extent (if any) that knowing/using the correct form (number/gender) of a verb's past participle is/should be considered part of knowing how to correctly conjugate that verb in compound tenses, maybe one could argue that "on" is not [always] conjugated like "il" when used/found in compound tenses (but only if one agrees with the position that the agreement of past participles [& adjectives] with "on" should follow normal agreement rules when "on" is not being used as an indefinite pronoun, which position might require the [weird, imo] pluralization of your example of "On est prêt[S?]).

Answer (score 3):

'On' means 'we' and is conjugated as a 3rd person singular.
 Example: `"On y va"` = `"Let's go!"`
  When writing formally or speaking politely, use 'nous' generally but the French use 'on' a lot when they speak. It is also translated as 'one' as in "one knows when to be quiet."

That is a bit formal, so when you see `'on'` think `'we'`. Remember, it is is the subject of the sentence where one would use `'on'`.